# Ho to get current view file in Middleware Laravel?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, factory, middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ViewTestMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // how get view file path 
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: well the request hasn't even made it to the 'action' yet before `$next($request);` so you couldn't possibly get it before that point

Comment: hmm in this case it should be here $response = $next($request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would let you pull the original view from the response.

```
$response = $next($request);
// assuming that was a view returned ...
$view = $response->original; // View object
$view->getPath(); // View path
...
```